# Directory is locked after creation of file while program is running

Tags: c#, directory, locked-files

After I created a file in a directory the directory is locked as long as my program which created the file is running. Is there any way to release the lock? I need to rename the directory couple of lines later and I always get an `IOException` saying "Access to the path "..." denied".

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(dstPath);
File.Copy(srcPath + "\\File1.txt", dstPath + "\\File1.txt"); // no lock yet
File.Create(dstPath + "\\" + "File2.txt"); // causes lock
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`File.Create(string path)` Creates a file and leaves the stream open.

you need to do the following:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(dstPath);
File.Copy(srcPath + "\\File1.txt", dstPath + "\\File1.txt");
using (var stream = File.Create(dstPath + "\\" + "File2.txt"))
{
    //you can write to the file here
}
```

The using statement asures you that the stream will be closed and the lock to the file will be released.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried closing your `FileStream`? e.g.

```
var fs = File.Create(dstPath + "\\" + "File2.txt"); // causes lock
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Note that it's good practice to wrap file open/create in `using`, in case of exceptions. Not significant for this one-liner, but if there was other code between the Create() and the Close() that could throw exceptions, it's necessary.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Agreed.  Arturo's solution is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you use a `using` statement:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(path))
{
   //....
}
```

but you should also be aware of using object initializers in using statements:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path) {Position = position})
{
  //....
}
```

in this case it will be compiled in:

```
var tmp = new FileStream(path);
tmp.Position = position;
var stream = tmp;

try
{ }
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
        ((IDisposable)stream).Dispose();
}
```

and if the `Position` setter throw exception, `Dispose()` will not being called for the temporary variable.

Comment: Which is not the case here; `File.Open(path)` and `File.Create(path)` cannot be expressed with object initialization because they are not constructors, they are static methods. 
The syntax in your second using statement won't even compile.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez: yes, there should be an object constructor for reproducing such scenario. i fixed it (FileStream insted of File.Open()).